# How does SUBSTRING work with a VARBINARY field?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Person (id decimal(25,0))
INSERT INTO #Person values (153121432060080000944513)
```

and the SQL statement below:

```
select substring(HASHBYTES('MD5', 
CAST(id AS varchar(24))),1,4)
from #person
```

I understand after reading the Hashbytes reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174415.aspx) that a VARBINARY is returned.  How does the substring function work with a VARBINARY. The SUBSTRING function above returns the following:

```
0x05DDF8D9
```

This is more than four characters long.  I know that 0x denotes a VARBINARY.  Why are there more than four characters in the substring?

Comment: The value is coded as hexadecimal, so each character in the output represents four bits -- typically half of a character in storage.  Two characters in the `0x` representation for each character in the string.  So, that is four characters.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the hexadecimal output with a string.  In all likelihood, your strings consist of one-byte characters encoded using ASCII.  Each byte -- consisting of 8 bits -- represents a character, typically by mapping a value between 0 and 127 to something we know and love.  "32" is a space.  "65" is "A" (capitalized).

The problem is:  How does this get represented when the "string" is really "binary"?  Suddenly, the computer no longer has a nice character set to map each character.  And, some characters pose a problem -- "delete", "new line", "carriage return", and the zero value are all ASCII characters with no recognizable printed output.

Let's dive down a level.  The letter A is represented by the bit sequence "01000001" (this is the binary form of the number 65).  A common way to represent this is by splitting it in half "0100" and "0001" and then interpreting each half as a number.  A hexadecimal (base 16) number system is used, because there are sixteen possibilities for four bits.  The first ten values are easy.  They are digits.  The other six (10 through 15) are represented using letters A - F.  These are typically capitalized.  And the whole value is has a leading "0x" prefix, by convention.

So, the bits "01000001" would be represented as 0x41.  Consider another example for "11001010".  This would become 0xCA.  If you like, you can then play games such as deciphering 0xC0DE or "0xBEADED" or "0xFEEFIEF0E".

Sorry this is so long.  Explaining this seems more interesting than the work I should be doing.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. However, 8 bits (ascii) is half of 16 (hex), rather than double. Sorry, I am a bit confused.

Comment: @w0051977 . . . 4 bits can represent the values from 0 to 15.  That is what hexadecimal is for.  It is sort of a coincidence that the "16" values in four bits happens to be twice the number of bits in an ASCII character.